# How to see if a norm is finite

Tags: normed-spaces

How do you know if $$||\frac{1}{\sqrt3},\frac{1}{\sqrt8}, ... , \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2-1}}, ... ||_2$$ is finite. So this means is $$\bigg( \sum _{n=2}^{\infty} | \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2-1}}|^2 \bigg) ^{\frac12}< \infty$$

Comment: For the usual 2-norm you missed ^2 of the absolute value.

Comment: You also start the sum at $n=2$, not $n=1$. Do you know why $\sum_n 1/n^2$ is finite?

Comment: @s.harp Yeah it is finite by ratio test or another one of those tests (been long). So if the inside of the bracket is finite, then the whole thing is finite? and same for infinite?

Comment: Depends on what bracket you mean. If you mean $|\cdot |^2$, then that is not the case as clearly $1$ is finite but $\sum_n^\infty 1$ is not finite. If you mean the $(\cdot)^{1/2}$ bracket, then note that you can define a root function on all of $\mathbb C$ to return again a well defined value. Although it is "strictly canonical" only on $\mathbb R_{≥0}$ (remember that the root has branch cuts).

Comment: @s.harp I see, i did in fact mean the (...)^0.5 bracket. I have a side question, what does the following mean "norms $||.||_p$ and $||.||_q$ ON $\ell ^p$"? What does it mean by 'on'?

Comment: @snowman a norm is defined "on" a vector space $A$ in the sense that it is a function on $A$. That is $\| \cdot \| : A \to \mathbb R$. There may be extra emphasis on the word on, since one uses the same name for norms on different vector spaces. For example the sup norm on $C(0,1)$ and on $C_C(\mathbb R)$ are both called the sup norm.

Comment: @s.harp so what is the difference between $||.||_p : \ell ^p \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $||.||_q : \ell ^p \rightarrow \mathbb R$ ? Like how can i prove that these are not equivalent if say p=1 and q= infinity?

Comment: i really don't understand what statements like decide whether Norms $||.||_1$ and $||.||_2 +||.||_3$ are equivalent on $\ell ^1$$.

Comment: For example the sequence where the first $n$ terms are $1/n^{1/p}$ (and the rest are zero) converges to zero in $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm, but not in $\|\cdot\|_p$ norm.

Comment: i really don't understand, would you be able to try explain more please

Comment: Two norms are equivalent if there are constants in $a, b  \in \mathbb R_{>0}$ so that $a\|\cdot\|_1 ≤ \|\cdot\|_2 ≤ b\|\cdot\|_1$. Notice that this inequality implies that if you have a sequence that converges wrt $\|\cdot\|_1$, it also converges wrt $\|\cdot\|_2$ (and the other way around, also they converge to the same element). If you write out the sequence above, you will find that it has constant norm $1$ in $\|\cdot\|_p$, but in $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ the norm is $1/n^{1/p}$, which converges to zero. So the norms cannot be equivalent.

Comment: @s.harp Thank you. One more thing,  if $1 \leq  p < q \leq ∞$, why do we have that the norm $||.||_q$ is a well-deﬁned norm on $\ell ^p$?

Comment: Apart from a finite amount of terms, the elements any sequence in $\mathscr l^p$ are smaller than 1. If $p<q<\infty$ and $|x|<1$ you have $|x|^p>|x|^q$. From these two observations you must note that from convergence of $\sum_n |x_n|^p$ the convergence of $\sum_n |x_n|^q$ must follow, since after a finite amount of terms the terms in the $q$ sum are all smaller than those in the $p$ sum.

Comment: @s.harp Can i just ask, what does it even mean for the norm to be well defined? I thought it was something like, if we have two different representations of the input, the output implies that those representations are equal.

Comment: A function $f: A \to B$ is well defined if it is indeed a function from $A$ to $B$, ie $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb N$, $x\mapsto x$ is not well defined. If you have different ways of denoting the elements of $A$, for example fractions in $\mathbb Q$, having a definition that gives different values for the same element depending on what way of denoting it is chose makes the object not well defined. In the case of these norms this is not the problem, what is the problem and what you have to check is if $x \in \mathscr l^p$ is that $\|x\|_q$ is not $\infty$ but in something in $\mathbb R_{≥0}$.

Comment: @s.harp I see. So if $p=1$ and $q= \infty$, and we want to prove that $||.||_{\infty}$ is well defined on $\ell ^1$. Let $(a_k)_{k \geq 1} \in \ell ^1$. So we know that $|a_k|^1<1$ for all $k$. What next? We need to show $\sup |a_k|^1 < \infty $ right?

Comment: It is not true that $|a_k|<1$ for all $k$. This is only eventually true, ie there exists an $N$ so that if $k>N$ you have $|a_k|<1$. You want to show that $\sup|a_k|<\infty$, but note that $\sum_k |a_k| < \infty$!

Comment: @s.harp So can we just write: Let $(a_k) \in \ell ^1$. Then $\sum |a_k|^1 < \infty$, which clearly means $\sup |a_k|^1 < \infty$. Hence $||.||_{\infty}$ is well defined on $\ell ^1$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @s.harp So if we wanted to prove $||.||_1$ and $||.||_{\infty}$ are not equivalent on $\ell ^1$, can we just say: Let $(1/k) \in \ell ^1$, then for $||.||_1$, we have $(\sum |1/k|^1)^{1/1}$ which diverges but for $||.||_{\infty}$, we have $\sup |1/k|^1 = 1 < \infty$ ??? Is that how we are meant to phrase it.

Comment: No, you cannot do that because $(1/k)$ does not lie in $\mathscr l^1$ (which is what you have shown just now). But what you can do is take the following sequence of elements in $\mathscr l^1$: The n-th element of the sequence is the element of $\mathscr l^1$ where the first $n$ terms are $1/n$, the rest are zero. (the formulation may be a bit awkward because the elements of $\mathscr l^1$ can also be seen as sequences). In $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ this converges to zero, but in $\|\cdot\|_1$ it has constant norm.

Comment: @s.harp oh wow that sounds so complex... is there any other sequence that u could use?

Comment: If you write it out it is quite simple, just awkward to write in typed format. (Ie think of a sensible notation for elements of $\mathscr l^1$ like $(x)\equiv\sum_k^\infty x_k e_k$ and then $(x)_n:=\sum_k^n 1/n\ e_k$). I think it is the simplest way to see that the two norms are not equivalent.

Comment: @s.harp how can something converge to zero in $||.||_{\infty}$ though? because you just take the maximum value of the sequence don't u?

Comment: $(x)_n$ is a sequence in $\mathscr l^1$. This means for each $n$, $(x)_n$ is an element of $\mathscr l^1$. In the norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ you have $\|(x)_n\|_\infty=1/n$, which converges to zero.

Comment: @s.harp Hi, we spoke before about if p=1 and q=inf, and we want to prove that $||.||_{\infty}$ is well defined. And you said i was correct in saying the following: Let $(a_k)_{k \geq 1} \in \ell ^1$, then $\sum |a_k|^1 < \infty$ which means (*) $\sup |a_k|^1 < \infty$. Hence it is well defined. But i was told that i need more justification on the (*) bit. I know what is going on and why it leads to the conclusion but cant phrase it simply. Please help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35818/discussion-between-s-harp-and-snowman).